# how to get a sound notification in terminal once a job has been completed

Tags: notifications, terminal, fedora, audio

I run jobs on a remote machine . The jobs take a few mins to complete and I'd like a sound notification on my local machine in order to know that the job has been completed . Can anybody suggest a command if exists, or a tool that does this ?

Thanks

EDIT : I run jobs on remote machine, but need a sound notification (which has to obviously happen on local machine) upon completion ! Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying you run them one-by-one from the command line?  I'm not in Linux atm, so I can't verify this, but I believe the bell escape character - "\a" - works in bash, so you should be able to do something like:

`./dojob; echo "\a"`

Again, this is off the top of my head, so test it with something like opening gedit followed by a bell or something.

Comment: That should work as intended, unless you're like me and have turned of the bell somewhere, and then proceeded to forget where.

Comment: @Sharat Chandra - For some reason I'm not able to comment on your original question (... but I can edit it?) Anyway, I could use a little more detail.  Do you mean you're SSHing into the remote machines and then starting jobs?  I'm having trouble thinking of a way to SSHin, and trigger sounds on your machine..

Comment: I think you need ``echo -e "\a"``, ``\e`` tells echo to interpret the backslash escapes